Read Dynamic Acrobat PDF in Python
I'm trying to read a dynamic Acrobat PDF in Python. However, this message is all that appears:
"Please wait. ..
If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents ofthe document, your PDF
viewer may not be able to display this type ofdocument."
I also tried opening it in FirefoxPortable, however same message. The weird thing: It does open on Firefox Portable on a different PC. Am I missing any settings or something?
I need to be able to get the contents of the PDF without Acrobat directly.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!
